# BackboneJS How to open View with Magnific Popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, popup

Is it possible to open a Backbone View with the `Magnific Popup`-plugin from http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/ ?

I want to create a Login Popup and I'm not sure how to do that. I have another View where I use the popup plugin like this:

```
events: {
'click .video' : 'popUp'
},

popUp: function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 $('.video').magnificPopup({
    disableOn: 700,
    type: 'iframe',
    mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
    removalDelay: 160,
    preloader: false,
    fixedContentPos: false
});
}
```

and then in my HTML template I simply do this:

```
<section>
    <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Naf5uJYGoiU" class="video">click here</a>
</section>
```

This works fine, but how to do this when I want to do a Login popup?

Please help! Thanks in advance...

Comment: What problem are you having? How is your *login-view* different from the one where you have implemented the popup plugin.

Comment: @Jack I'm thinking about the `<a href="">` - since I have to specify the `href` to make the Magnific Popup work.I dont really know what to put in it. The Path to the View?